# How can I send an SMS via Oracle 11g? The client is toad and in India I have to send an SMS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to create a procedure to send an SMS to an Indian mobile user via an Oracle 11g database.

I have searched a lot, but I can't find a neat procedure.

Comment: So, please let us know what have you researched and tried.

Comment: Researched about sending sms thru email in which service provider provides method to send SMS thru their local domain n using SMTP connection. So I can't find exact procedure and that's what iam asking, I hope these research will satisfy u that iam not letting u to do my homework....

Comment: I don't know about India but I use a local SMS gateway that provides a simple http API which I call using UTL_HTTP.

Comment: What do you mean by *"The client is toad"*? The derogatory term or [Toad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toad_(software)) the database management toolset from Quest Software? "Client" as in software client?

Answer (score 1):

Sending e-mails from Oracle database is one thing but sending SMS from the database is a whole lot of other things.

You will need the service of any third party who can provide APIs for your requirement. (Handle sending of sms from the application)

Try [smscountry](http://www.smscountry.com/productdetails.aspx)

Comment: But I searched n I found that there is something called send sms through email

Comment: can you post the link here so that i will have an idea.. According to my knowledge, sending an email to +91xxxxxxxxxx@<carrier>.com used to work before but i think it may be depricated long back but still research and try to do the same to your phone number. If it works, then you can use the DB to send a simple email which will serve your purpose.

Comment: Here u go: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_send_email_from_oracle_cell_phone_mobile_sms_device.htm

Comment: here is a link to write PL/SQL (make it into a procedure) on how to send email from oracle. [link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL)

Comment: It is not really worth to use an sms gateway (sms through email) for different reasons. 1> It will be a pain in the ass to manage a phone number and the email domain for different users. 2> You will have no feedback to know if the sms has reached your customer/client. I suggest you to use an API which will be easy to implement and would also not cost too much

Comment: If you succeed to send sms through email, Let us know too.. Post the correct answer and help the needy.

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap the entire procedure and call it against a table trigger or through a button click available with user form

```
SET serveroutput ON
SET Define OFF

DECLARE
    HTTP_REQ      UTL_HTTP.REQ;
    HTTP_RESP     UTL_HTTP.RESP;
    URL_TEXT      VARCHAR2(32767);
    URL VARCHAR2(2000);

     SMS_MSG VARCHAR2(160) := 'Congratulations! Your database has been configured propoerly for sending SMS through a 3rd party SMS Gateway';

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
--Based on your service provider, the following link format may differ from
--What we have specified below!    

URL := 'http://yourwebsmsdomain.com/alerts/api/web2sms.php?username=demo&password=demo2&to=95xxxxxxx&sender=ODBSMS&message='||
UTL_URL.Escape(SMS_MSG,TRUE); 
--UTL_URL.Escape manages escape characters like SPACE between words in a message.



    HTTP_REQ  := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(URL);

    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(HTTP_REQ, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
    HTTP_RESP := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(HTTP_REQ);

    -- Process Request
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            URL_TEXT := null;
            UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(HTTP_RESP, URL_TEXT, TRUE);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(URL_TEXT);

            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN EXIT;
        END;
    END LOOP;

    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(HTTP_RESP);
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up a web service (PHP file that you can call from Oracle) which you can call using soap_api.

Comment: Which web service? Web services have to be PHP? SOAP_API is the only way to call them?

Comment: What do you mean by *"soap_api"*? Is it the name of a PHP function? Or do you mean *"a [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)"*? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29467762/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).